# How to display item multiple times on button click in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As you can see I am displaying a checkbox along with its label on t a button click. At this moment I am only able to display one checkbox at a time. Is there a way to make it so I can display multiple?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class TodoBody extends Component {

    state = {
        buttonPress: false,
        checked: false
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop:'70px'}}>
                <div className="todo__body" style={{margin:'auto'}}>
                    <h1 style={{textAlign:'center', textDecoration:'underline'}}>To-do's</h1>
                    <div className="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="New Task" id="task" />
                        <div className="input-group-append">
                            <a className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={this.addTask}>Add</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {this.state.buttonPress? 
                        [
                            <div style={{float:'left', paddingLeft:'25px'}} className="checkbox-container">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1"/>
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">{document.getElementById('task').value}</label>
                            </div>
                        ]
                    : <span/>}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    addTask = () => {
        this.setState({buttonPress:true});
    }
}

export default TodoBody;
```

Comment: if you want to display multiple tasks, you should probably change your state so it supports that

Comment: Do you know how I would do that? I can figure it out I am just curious at how your approach would be

Comment: From what I can see, the `TodoBody` is probably the wrong one, you should add a task on a parent component that shows all the todo's

Comment: Are you trying to show 1 more checkbox every time the button is clicked? Or do you have a certain number of checkboxes you wanna show as soon as the button is clicked (where the number of checkboxes never changes)?

Comment: I am trying to show 1 more checkbox when button is clicked yes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make a seperate component for checkbox, in this case name it **Checkbox**. You can try to create an empty array as initial state. Then just add to it for every button click. Then map the array in your render method, call Checkbox component for each:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const Checkbox = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ float: 'left', paddingLeft: '25px' }} className="checkbox-container">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">{document.getElementById('task').value}</label>
    </div>
  );
}

class TodoBody extends Component {

  state = {
    tasks: [],
    checked: false
  };

  addTask = () => {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks;
    this.setState({ tasks: [ tasks.length, ...tasks ] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '70px' }}>
        <div className="todo__body" style={{ margin: 'auto' }}>
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center', textDecoration: 'underline' }}>To-do's</h1>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="New Task" id="task" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <a className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={() => this.addTask()}>Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          {!!this.state.tasks.length ?
            this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => <Checkbox key={i} />)
            : <span />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoBody;
```